# Help designing which metals are associated with specific magical powers in my magic system

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, magic, warfare, history

In my world, one of the magic systems involves people crushing special objects in their gauntlets to gain the dormant energy that exists within them. Essentially, imagine there are certain energy in the environment that give certain powers, but in order to use them for short periods of time, they must be 'absorbed' into the body.

I already have uses / limitations / consequences / how this actual magic system is used laid out. **But what I need is to figure out the metals best associated with said powers - whether due to historical associations, traditional uses, etc.** Here's a list of metals and what abilities they should grant.

---

### **The first 4 below are the weaker ones.**

1. Lets you *sense others currently using magical powers and mentally contact them at short-distance*. Currently, I've put this as Aluminum.
2. *Lets you absorb and release small amounts of elemental power (fire, water, etc)*. Currently put this as Tin.
3. Slightly *improves your body's resistance against magical energy. Also reduces your body's need for food/sleep/etc to **feel** healthy*. Currently put this as Brass.
4. *Slightly improves your physical strength and pain tolerance.* Currently Iron.

---

### **The following 4 are the more powerful ones.**

1. Allows you to *manipulate friction of your body and objects you touch.*
2. Allows you to *tear through the wards/protections made by other magic systems.* Essentially a 'magical-energy field breaker'
3. Allows you to *manipulate metals and alloys.*
4. Allows you to *manipulate gravitational/electric/magnetic fields around you.*

For these, I wasn't sure what to put. I was considering doing the precious metals - **silver / gold / platinum / palladium** - but I'm worried this will have *unforeseen consequences on the evolution of technology and on the economy.* Plus I'd probably be throwing my aforementioned associations out the window.

In terms of actual criteria:

- Base metals and alloys are both fine.
- They should have **historical significance OR actual scientific significance**. Like a metal being associated historically with elements, or being used in witchcraft for a specific reason, etc. Alternatively, something like Sulfur being related to something like fire powers might make sense too.
- **The more legitimately logical relation between the metal and the power, the better** - ie 'ruby because red for the fire power' is a bit weak and the two aren't really that related besides the coloration in my opinion, but 'obsidian because solidified by magma for the elemental power' is much more coherent.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81477/discussion-on-question-by-doplin-help-designing-which-metals-are-associated-with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Allows you to manipulate friction of your body and objects you touch.**

Gold, silver, copper and platnum all have low friction coefficients, so any of them could be used.

> **Allows you to tear through the wards/protections made by other magic systems.**

Haven't seen any info on wards and how to break them.
Could use one of the metals that doesn't tarnish, such as gold or platinum, but one that is crystalline like Bismuth could be pretty interesting as well.

> **Allows you to manipulate metals and alloys.**

Mercury actually could be interesting for this one, as it [breaks the bonds of many other metals](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-mercury-dissolve-many-metals-such-as-gold-silver-zinc-aluminum-etc-but-not-iron), giving it the appearance of disolving them.

> **Allows you to manipulate gravitational/electric/magnetic fields around you.**

[Magnetite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetite) could be what you are looking for, as it is naturally magnetic. It might be too similar to iron for you though, so as a backup you could use a metal with good conductive properties such as copper. It can be used to conduct/manipulate electricity and radio.